# Schengen visa refusal with an alert and chance of getting UK visa

Tags: uk, schengen-visas

My application for Schengen visa was rejected twice, "the information regarding the justification for the purpose of intended stay was not reliable".

Second time  but that time an alert was issued. I couldn't understand why and contacted a lawyer who said that it will cost me thousands of euro and my purpose of removing the alert may not be achieved so  I am extremly worried that this alert may affect my chances of securing a UK visa. What can I do? Does this alert affect UK visa? AND how can I lift this alert?

Comment: We don’t know what kind of alert it is and cannot determines if it will affect your UK visa application or not. What you can do is apply for the UK visa and answer all questions truthfully and hope, you’ll find out soon. To lift the alert (if it can even be lifted), like the other lawyer said, you get an experienced attorney and pay good money and they give it a shot. No shortcuts.

Comment: If your reason for applying to visit the UK is to sit the PLAB exam, the brief comment in this question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e may be relevant. The UK application asks about previous refusals, with two under your belt your chances of success are pretty low

Answer (score 8):

If it's a Schengen Information System alert “for the purposes of refusing entry in the Schengen Area”, i.e. article 24 of Regulation (EC) No 1987/2006 (as seems likely), I believe the UK never had access to those. It did have access to other alerts in the SIS but currently doesn't. Appeals are strictly under national rules so you do need to follow whatever process Greece offers and, indeed, to hire a local lawyer.

However, you suffered two refusals less than two years ago, by two different countries, one of which was singled out as warranting an alert. Clearly, your circumstances were seen as risky. The UK doesn't have a reputation for leniency and your situation is unlikely to have changed enough to give you a good shot at obtaining a visa, quite apart from any alert. You need to evaluate that very carefully before any new application, otherwise you would just be wasting money and making matters worse.

**In other words, the alert probably doesn't affect your chances very much but they seem very low to begin with.** The Covid-19 pandemic doesn't help either, the British authorities will look at the purpose for your travel and will want to see that it is essential and absolutely cannot be postponed. Otherwise, it will look like a pretext and that will be another reason to refuse the visa.

Note that you will probably be asked to report prior refusals as part of the application procedure and trying to lie could also lead to very serious consequences (refusal of course but also a very long ban from the UK, typically much longer than bans from EU countries).

Comment: Has anyone been able to lift the alert ? I just feel thats unfair and I havent done anything wrong to deserve this ?

Comment: @Samar There are court cases about that, some people did succeed in getting a decision from this or that court (but the cases that make it to literature usually involve other complexities, multiple courts, etc.) I have no idea how common this is. Alerts expire too (after five years at most for the initial alert, which could however be reentered by the same country if you received a longer ban).

Comment: Beyond that you have provided zero details on what this alert even is, it's difficult to provide useful info. I am not saying the system as a whole is fair but I think focusing on the alert is the wrong way to approach this. Everything suggests your application is very weak, that it doesn't fulfill the requirements or otherwise raises doubts in European consulates. You first need to realise and address this, otherwise you are going nowhere.

Comment: The alert was issued for the purpose of refusal entry . They can reenter the alert if I recieved a ban from where ? I believe if I applied to any schengen visa , it will be rejected due to this alert so I dont plan to apply again to a schdngen area, however I want to lift it if possible , its a red sign when I apply anywhere. I read somewhere in the site that I can send a request for access and another request for correction and deletion ? Or the lawyer is really necessary ? And how can I get a lawyer for this purpose? Thanks

Comment: @Samar The alert is just a way for Greece to inform other countries of a ban. If and when someone is banned from entering by a Schengen country, that country would enter an alert in the system. And if you are still banned when the alert expires, there is no reason they could not enter it again. In at least one prominent case, [other countries issued an alert after the first one was cancelled](https://www.ceps.eu/ceps-publications/other-side-moons-schengen-information-system-and-human-rights-task-national-courts/).

Comment: Realistically a lawyer is necessary because you will need to do it in Greek and have cogent arguments. You're always free to do it yourself if you want but it's unlikely to succeed. The Greek government is under no obligation to do anything just because you wish the alert would not exist.

Comment: Thanks for the information . Anyway to get a lawyer invovled in similar cases ??